# how to process JSON from Axios call in Scala

Tags: json, scala, axios

I have the next axios call:

```
const userInfo = {}; 
    userInfo['id'] = row['id'];
    userInfo[cellName] = cellValue;


axios.post(
      getServerInfo() + '/updateUser', userInfo
     ).  .....
```

where:

```
function getServerInfo() {
    return 'http://'+ window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port;
}
```

I need to write a controller in Scala to print the info of userInfo at the scala terminal. How can this be done? I need to be able to get every field value of userInfo into a Scala object.

Answer (score 0):

I basically followed:

```
class InfoFromJson() extends Controller {

def updateUser = Action {  request =>
        val body: AnyContent = request.body
        val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson
         println(jsonBody);
        // Expecting json body
        jsonBody.map { json =>
                Ok("Got: " + (json \ "lastName").as[String])
        }.getOrElse {
                BadRequest("Expecting application/json request body")
         }

    }
}
```

based on info from:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers